# NodeJS socket.io event fired from client side but not receiving on server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a simple turn based game in node.js and I had everything working 100% running with a locally hosted mongoDB, the socket events were working fine, however when i changed from a local db (using mongo) to mLab mongoDB hosting it stopped working, i could still log in and register accounts correctly, the database was still returning the exact same results, so it is obviously having no trouble connecting and querying the database. But i'm completely lost at what the problem could be. When i change the database URL it would never fire the socket.emit('key') event;

However it does fire the ('find match') event on the client socket but the server never handles it. (it doesn't log "findMatch" on server).

the server is logging "connection" but never receiving any other socket events.

Even if i don't get a solution i am just completely stuck trying to debug where the problem is occurring, so any sort of input would be really really appreciated

This is socket debug log i'm getting in console.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
looking for match
socket.io-1.2.0.js:1 socket.io-client:manager writing packet %j +3s Object {type: 2, data: Array[1], nsp: "/"}
socket.io-1.2.0.js:1 socket.io-parser encoding packet %j +2s Object {type: 2, data: Array[1], nsp: "/"}
socket.io-1.2.0.js:1 socket.io-parser encoded %j as Object +0ms 2["findMatch"]
socket.io-1.2.0.js:1 engine.io-client:socket flushing 1 packets in socket +2s
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


var express = require('express');
app = express();
http = require('http').Server(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
mongoose = require('mongoose');
passport = require('passport');
flash = require('connect-flash');
morgan = require('morgan');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
session = require('express-session');
methodOverride = require('method-override');
User = require('./models/user');


var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error);

app.use(express.static('public', {redirect: false}));
app.use(express.static('private/tests', {redirect: false}));


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(session({secret: 'password'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


require('./routes')(app,passport);

var rooms = [];


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("connection");

    socket.on('key', function(data){
        console.log("key");
        socket._id = data.user_id;
        socket.nickname = data.username;
        socket.rank = data.rank;

        socket.on('findMatch', function() {
            console.log('findMatch');
            //do some other stuff
        });
```

And then on the client side i have this setup

```
scotchApp.controller('lobbyController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/play').then(function successCallback(results){
        socket.on('connect',function(){
            console.log("emit key")
            socket.emit('key',{
                user_id: results.data._id,
                username: results.data.local.email,
                rank: results.data.local.rank,
            });
        });

        $scope.findMatch = function(){
            console.log('looking for match');
            socket.emit('findMatch')
        };
```

Comment: I don't have an entire idea about your code, I'm just guessing, that you introduced a race condition, why ? just because when you registered a database in a external service (outside your network and on internet) you added a small latency in your logic, and maybe a call can overrun another one, that can cause a invalid state and make your code not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the issue.